# Query with a field to with a specific format

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have an SQL table with a field `REFERENCE`.
Most of the references are like this: `A123B45*`
I mean:

```
1 letter, 3 digits, 1 letter, 2 digits, anything
```

But some are *different*, like `AB123C12` they start by **2** letters.

I want to make a *query* to get only the lines with a reference corresponding to the *first example* `A123B45*`.

I already tried this:

```
select REFERENCE from facture where REFERENCE REGEXP "[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[.]*"
```

But this doesn't work because I have *also* lines starting by *two letters*.

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}"`: I've added *anchor* `^` (reference *starts* from regex)

Comment: *anchor* `^` means "beginning of the string"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `^` *anchor*, since `reference` must *start* from (not *contain*) the regular expression:

```
    select REFERENCE 
      from facture 
     where REFERENCE REGEXP "^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}"
```

What's going on:

```
   AB123C12 <-- doesn't start from the pattern 
    ^     ^
    |-----| <-- but contains the pattern
```

that's why you had *false positives*